# Google Sheet Script Fuction to Count Words in a File Link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have some problem, i try to count the number of words contained in the link "D4" with the following script.

```
function wordCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var fileUrl = sheet.getRange("E" + activeRow).getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileUrl.slice(fileUrl.indexOf("/d/") + 3, fileUrl.indexOf("/edit")));
  var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var count = content.match(/\b\w+\b/g).length;
  sheet.getRange("F" + activeRow).setValue(count);
}
```

However, the script counts all the links in column D4 and returns the result in column F4.
[the code count all word in file link "D4"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Yak.png)

How to make this script count each row only, for example it will count the number of words in file link D4 and put the result in F4, then count the number of words in link D5 and put the result in F5 and so on?

How to make this script count each row only, for example it will count the number of words in file link D4 and put the result in F4, then count the number of words in link D5 and put the result in F5 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your sample image, it seems that your question is different from your sample image. So, in this answer, I believe your sample image and prepare an answer. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function wordCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var fileUrls = sheet.getRange("E4:E" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var values = fileUrls.map(([fileUrl]) => {
    if (!fileUrl) return [null];
    var id = "";
    try {
      id = fileUrl.slice(fileUrl.indexOf("/d/") + 3, fileUrl.indexOf("/edit"));
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var count = content.match(/\b\w+\b/g).length;
      return [count];
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log({id, error}); // When you want to check the error, please use this line. By this, you can see it in the log.
      return [null];
    }
  });
  sheet.getRange(4, 6, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the URLs are retrieved from the cells "E4:E". And, `count` is retrieved from each row. And, the result values are put to column "F".
- From your reply, I'm worried that there might be Google Document you cannot read. So, I used try-catch. When an error occurs, the file ID is skipped.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, [i got this error](https://i.imgur.com/46ishOf.png), can you help me?

Comment: @Aldo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, in this case, it is considered that the invalid file ID is used. So, please confirm your URLs again. If you cannot understand my reply, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, in your actual situation, the URLs are put in column "D" or "E"? I cannot still understand your actual situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: thank you, please use this [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BZaM_rTUmVwI8F1XWOLt8N8OgjN852SmE_2rQaKr92U/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you for your help, there's no error at that script, but I think the value it's right either [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/KWMerPl.png) and just count 7 rows from E7 to E12. Do you know what's happen to this code?

Comment: @Aldo Thank you for replying. About your reply, when `console.log({id, error});` is used by removing `//`, you can see the error message in the log. And, I have to apologize that I don't know your actual situation. So, please confirm the error in the log. For example, how about confirming the following points? 1. All URLs are valid URLs of Google Documents? 2. For example, DOCX files are included? DOCX files cannot be used. Please be careful about this. 3. Do You have permission for reading the values from all Google Documents?

Comment: @Aldo If you cannot understand my reply, can you provide the file of one of the URLs where the count is not retrieved? By this, I would like to check it. But, in that case, it supposes that you have permission for reading. Please be careful about this.